# How can I bind non-null self referencing entity?

Tags: jpa, many-to-one, self-referencing-table

I'm trying to bind a table looks like this

```
some_id   BIGINT PK
parent_id BIGINT    NN '0'
```

As you can see,

- It looks like a self-referencing entity
- No FK for `parent_id`
- `parent_id` is not nullable and defaults to `0`

How can I bind?

Does following mapping just fine?

```
class Some {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne // optional?
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "some_id")
    private Some parent;
}
```

How, in other words, can I map `0` to `null`?

Answer (score 1):

I think better to harden the existence of a root element by adding the root to the table:

```
INSERT INTO some (some_id, parent_id) VALUES (0, 0);
COMMIT;
```

This way, that entry with `some_id = 0` will now serve as the root element, and make any references with `parent_id = 0` a valid reference.

I do not think there is a way to map 0 to NULL - not with the way JPA works, not for reference id's.